# passport.authenticate() gets called twice only on error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am authenticating the user using Ldap authentication. This works fine during a successful authentication or when the user provides incorrect credentials. But in case of an error being thrown the passport.authenticate() function gets called twice and i get the below error.

```
_http_outgoing.js:470
throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the 
client
```

So why does passport.authenticate function gets called twice only on error. Below is the code used for authentication.

```
let callCnt = 0

function pPortAuth(req,res,next) {
//Fetch the roles of the gid from the database
console.log("Called Here")
passport.authenticate('ldapauth', { session: false }, function (err, user, 
info) {
    console.log("Hetre " + req.method)
    ++callCnt
    console.log(callCnt)

    if (err || !user) {
        if (err && (err.code == 'ETIMEDOUT' || err.code == 'ENOTFOUND')) {
            console.log("Could not reach Ldap Server" + err.code)

            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Could 
    not reach Ldap Server' })
        }else if(!user){
            console.log("Authentication Failed or not a valid user")
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 
   'Authentication Failed' });
        }
    }

    let roles = (user.sAMAccountName == 'g705615')?['readWrite']: 
    ['readOnly']
    console.log(roles)
    return res.send({
        success: true,
        gid: user.sAMAccountName,
        name: user.name,
        token: jwt.sign({ sub: user.sAMAccountName, roles: roles, 
   loggedInUsername: user.name }, config.secret)
    });
})(req,res,next)
}
```

And below is the log

```
Called Here
Hetre POST
1
Could not reach Ldap ServerENOTFOUND
Hetre POST
2
Could not reach Ldap ServerENOTFOUND
```

If you see the function `function pPortAuth(req,res,next)` gets called only once but the `passport.authenticate()` function gets called twice on error.

Can anyone please tell me where i am making a mistake

UPDATE

```
//users.controller.js
let express = require('express');
let userAuth = express.Router();
let expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
let passport = require('passport') 
let config = require("../config.json")
let userAuthSvc = require('../_services/user.service')

let Ldap = require('../config/ldap.config');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
done(null,user)
})
passport.deserializeUser((user,done) => {
done(null,user)
})

passport.use(Ldap)

let initializePport = passport.initialize();

//userAuth.use(userAuthSvc.pportInit);
userAuth.post('/ldapLogin',initializePport, authenticate)

function authenticate (req, res, next) {
userAuthSvc.pportAuth(req, res, next);
}

//user.service.js
let passport = require('passport') 

function pPortAuth(req,res,next) {
//Fetch the roles of the gid from the database
console.log("Called Here")
passport.authenticate('ldapauth', { session: false }, function (err, user, 
info) {
    console.log("Hetre " + req.method)
    ++callCnt
    console.log(callCnt)

    if (err || !user) {
        if (err && (err.code == 'ETIMEDOUT' || err.code == 'ENOTFOUND')) {
            console.log("Could not reach Ldap Server" + err.code)

            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Could 
  not reach Ldap Server' })
        }else if(!user){
            console.log("Authentication Failed or not a valid user")
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 
 'Authentication Failed' });
        }
    }

    let roles = (user.sAMAccountName == 'g705615')?['readWrite']: 
 ['readOnly']
    console.log(roles)
    return res.send({
        success: true,
        gid: user.sAMAccountName,
        name: user.name,
        token: jwt.sign({ sub: user.sAMAccountName, roles: roles, 
 loggedInUsername: user.name }, config.secret)
    });
 })(req,res,next)
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the endpoint you're using to achieve this as well please? e.g. `app.post('/myapi',passport.authenticate etc etc)`

Comment: i am calling the function pPortAuth() from a controller like this `userAuth.use(userAuthSvc.pportInit);
userAuth.post('/ldapLogin', authenticate)

function authenticate (req, res, next) {
    userAuthSvc.pportAuth(req, res, next);
}`

Comment: Well right there is your issue, `.use` will add that function as middleware, you're doing that and then you're doing it in the function again, so the request would be `routehit > userAuthSvc.pportInit > userAuthSvc.pportInit` either remove the `.use` or remove the `userAuthSvc.pportAuth(req, res, next);` in the function. P.S, it's better to edit that information into the question rather than put it as a comment.

Comment: @George : I tried what you suggested and still was getting the same error. I have updated the question with some adjustments as per you said. But still am facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Another place you can get multiple calls to passport is from your strategy.
Check the callbacks inside your strategy function and that the inner user validation function only calls back once.

For me it was forgetting to put return in front of one of the callbacks in my username db lookup function, causing two callbacks.

```
function strategy(username, password, cb) {
    getEmailFromDB(username, async (err, user) => {
        console.log('stragegy res',err,user);
        if (err) { 
            console.log('lookup error',err);
            return cb(err);
        }
        if (!user) { 
            console.log('bad username');
            return cb(null, false); 
        }
        ...


function getEmailFromDB(id, cb) {
    process.nextTick(async () => {
        try {
            var account = await r.table('users').get(id).run(rconn)
            if(!account) {
                console.log('User doesnt exist',id);
                return cb(true);                       // had forgot return here
            }
            cb(null, {
                'id'        : account.id,
                'name'      : account.name,
                'password'  : account.password,
                'roles'     : account.roles 
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Lookup error for user',id);
            cb(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that i could come up with for my problem was to prevent the response being sent twice.
The problem i think is that when the `passport.authenticate()` function encounters the error `ENOTFOUND` it calls the callback again as i believe that is not handled properly. So to overcome this issue i just put a check to see if the headers were already sent and if yes then just return from the function else send a response. Below is my code, please comment on it if you need any assistance.

```
app.post('/ldapLogin', function (req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('ldapauth', { session: false }, function (err, user, info) {

    let resObj = {}
    let resStatus 
    if (err || !user) {
        if (err && (err.code == 'ETIMEDOUT' || err.code == 'ENOTFOUND')) {
            resStatus = res.status(400)
            resObj['success'] = false
            resObj['message'] = 'Could not reach Ldap Server'

        }else if(!user){
            console.log("Authentication Failed or not a valid user")
            resStatus = res.status(400)
            resObj['success'] = false
            resObj['message'] = 'Authentication Failed'
        }
    }else{
        resStatus = res
        let roles = (user.sAMAccountName == 'xxxxx')?['readWrite']:['readOnly']
        resObj['success'] = true
        resObj['gid'] = user.sAMAccountName
        resObj['name'] = user.name
        resObj['token'] = jwt.sign({ sub: user.sAMAccountName, roles: roles, loggedInUsername: user.name }, config.secret)
    } 
    if(res.headersSent)
    return
    return resStatus.send(resObj);
})(req, res, next)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and solved by changing the error handler middleware to force stopping request's progression. in fact, the error handler middleware must stop the request.

the wring error handler middleware:

```
export const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(400).send({errors: [{message: 'Something went wrong.'}]});
};
```

the correct error handler middleware:

```
export const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(400).send({errors: [{message: 'Something went wrong.'}]});
};
```

the differenc is just a simple **"return"** keyword :)